# How do I dry up setter side-effects on views?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently going back and cleaning up some (very) old code, as part of building out some new features.

On of the anti-patterns I'm trying to fix is that my view controller was getting a little bit too close to a god class, trying to do everything inside itself instead of letting smaller sub-views do some of the work.  I'm trying to move things so that the state lives in the VC, which it passes into the subviews to act on.  Very much like how react has containers that pass props into components.

The problem I'm having is that those subviews aren't necessarily loaded & ready to accept their initial state when that state is passed into the root view controller.

A really simplified version is:

```
class DemoVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        subView?.propertyClass = self.propertyClass
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView!
    var propertyClass:PropertyClass!{
        didSet{
            subView?.propertyClass = propertyClass
            //More side effects
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm now propagating the data in two places: once in the setter (good), but I also have to pass it on the view did load.  For one entry, that's not necessarily that bad.  I'm up to four actual pieces of state I need to track, and I'm nowhere near done.  The idea of a viewDidLoad method containing twenty different variations on `subview1.property = self.property` -- with different properties, different subviews, often repeating the same property over multiple subviews -- seems a little excessive to me.  Is there a better design pattern I could be using here, or am I stuck with it?

Comment: Use `protocol`s and `.subviews` to perform on all subviews.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini that's a fascinating reply.  Unfortunately, not all replies are answers.  Care to provide a bit more detail?

Comment: Unfortunately it is ios13 only, but [`@IBSegueAction`](https://sarunw.com/posts/better-dependency-injection-for-storyboards-in-ios13/) is really neat

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `protocol` and `subviews` property to reduce the code:

```
protocol PropertyHandler {
    func setProperties(_ propertyClass: Any) // Could be the type you need instead of `Any`
}
```

This will force your custom views to implement the function.

```
extension MyCustomView: PropertyHandler {
    func setProperties(_ propertyClass: Any) {
        // Set properties
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this on all subviews that conforming to the `protocol`:

```
var propertyClass: PropertyClass! {
    didSet {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            guard let propertyHandler = subview as? PropertyHandler else { continue }
            propertyHandler.setProperties(propertyClass)
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Update:

Also you can use the power of `generic`s:

```
protocol PropertyHandler {
    func setProperties<T>(_ propertyClass: T)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Any` though. Make `setProperties` a generic method instead by `func setProperty<T>(_ property: T)`. Also, don't do a type check and then force cast. Use optional casting instead.

Comment: Although those are not causing issues, I was thinking about it @DávidPásztor . But I can't specialize non-generic type. Can you please do me a favor and give me hand to enhance the answer?

Comment: Sacrificing type safety almost always causes issues :) "But I can't specialize non-generic type" That's just incorrect. You can add generic methods to non-generic types. Only generic properties require the type itself to be generic.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm always seeking knowledge of experienced people in the community. I changed the answer a bit @DávidPásztor. What do you think now?

Comment: Thank you for detailing your answer.  Now I get how you connected protocols with the subviews property.

Comment: I reverted it back to more simpler version (beside the generic version). I hope you got the idea.

Comment: So looking at this, this solution only works if each property class is unique -- e. g. you don't have a 'currentItem' and 'nextItem' scenario.

Comment: The `ViewController` is responsible to pass need values to it owned views. 'currentItem' and 'nextItem' scenario is usually used in a middleware. The idea is to make all subviews conforming to same protocol, so they will look same from the parent controller and then you can apply a single function on all of them since they have same interface available.

Comment: I don't see how middleware changes the fact that some of my subviews need to know both what the current item and the next item are.  My list view needs to style each of them differently, for example (applying an 'active' and 'next' label as appropriate)